# Change between different background-images while you click on an image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kind of a newbie to design websites at all, and I have tried to find answers on my question without any success. (at least not any answers that could help me understand how I should do it)

Anyway. I'm doing this website where I want to change the background image on the website (with the connected pages) between a handfull numbers of images, when I click on another image. I also want the background-image to stay the same, even when I jump between the different pages.

Can someone explain how I should do? Gladly in a "Web-design for dummies way". (I'm in a class for web design in school, but the teacher can't explain it)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to point you in the right directions.
To do something when a user interface element is clicked you need the onclick event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click). The next thing that you have to do is somehow persist an image change for the user (or maybe for all users? you did not specify). You could do this for example with the cookies Web API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). Then you would of course also need to load the image stored in that cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what framework you are using, but I think the best way to do this is to include the background images in a css class like so:

`.background-image-1 {
  background-image: url("../path/to/image1")
}`

`.background-image-2 {
  background-image: url("../path/to/image2")
}`

Then adding an event handler to the click on the image that you want to change the background with. In the event handler you can then dynamically switch the css class of the body. That would probably look something like this:

`document.getElementById('idForBody').className = 'background-image-2';`

Hope this helps!